# Python - How to add delimiter and remove line breaks in CSV output?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, delimiter

I am doing this for the first time and so far have setup a simple script to fetch 2 columns of data from an API
The data comes through and I can see it with print command
Now I am trying to write it to CSV and setup the code below which creates the file but I can't figure out how to:
1. Remove the blank lines in between each data row
2. Add delimiters to the data which I want to be " "
3. If a value such as IP is blank then just show " "
I searched and tried all sorts of examples but just getting errors
My code snippet which writes the CSV successfully is

```
import requests
import csv
import json

# Make an API call and store response
url = 'https://api-url-goes-here.com'
filename = "test.csv"

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=('User','PWD'))
print(f"Status code: {r.status_code}")

#Store API response in a variable
response_dict = r.json()

#Open a File for Writing
f = csv.writer(open(filename, "w", encoding='utf8'))

# Write CSV Header
f.writerow(["Computer_Name", "IP_Addresses"])

for computer in response_dict["advanced_computer_search"]["computers"]:
    f.writerow([computer["Computer_Name"],computer["IP_Addresses"]])
```

CSV output I get looks like this:

> Computer_Name,IP_Addresses
>
> HYDM002543514,
>
> HYDM002543513,10.93.96.144 - AirPort - en1
>
> HYDM002544581,192.168.1.8 - AirPort - en1 / 10.93.224.177 -
> GlobalProtect - gpd0
>
> HYDM002544580,10.93.80.101 - Ethernet - en0
>
> HYDM002543515,192.168.0.6 - AirPort - en0 / 10.91.224.58 -
> GlobalProtect - gpd0
>
> CHAM002369458,10.209.5.3 - Ethernet - en0
>
> CHAM002370188,192.168.0.148 - AirPort - en0 / 10.125.91.23 -
> GlobalProtect - gpd0
>
> MacBook-Pro,

I tried adding

```
csv.writer(f, delimiter =' ',quotechar =',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

after the f = csv.writer line but that creates an error:
**TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method**

I am sure its something simple but just can't find the correct solution to implement in the code I have. Any help is appreciated.

Also, does the file get closed automatically? Some examples suggest to use something like f.close() but that causes errors. Do I need it? The file seems to get created fine as-is.

Comment: "creates errors" -> please be more specific

Comment: TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use pandas package to write `.csv` file, which is a most used package for data analysis.

For your problem:

```py
import requests
import csv
import json
import pandas

# Make an API call and store response
url = 'https://api-url-goes-here.com'
filename = "test.csv"

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=('User','PWD'))
print(f"Status code: {r.status_code}")

#Store API response in a variable
response_dict = r.json()

#collect data to build pandas.DataFrame
data = []
for computer in response_dict["advanced_computer_search"]["computers"]:
    # filter blank line
    if computer["Computer_Name"] or computer["IP_Addresses"]:
        data.append({"Computer_Name":computer["Computer_Name"],"IP_Addresses":computer["IP_Addresses"]})

pandas.DataFrame(data=data).to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

if you want use `" "` to separate value, you can set `sep=" "` in the last line output the `.csv` file. However, I recommend to use `,` as delimiters due to it's a common standard. Also much more configs could be set for DataFrame.to_csv() method, you can check the official docs. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

As you said in comment, pandas is not a standard python package. You can simply open a file and write lines to that file, with the lines you build manually. For example:

```py
import requests
import csv
import json

# Make an API call and store response
url = 'https://api-url-goes-here.com'
filename = "test.csv"

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=('User','PWD'))
print(f"Status code: {r.status_code}")

#Store API response in a variable
response_dict = r.json()

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=('User','PWD'))
print(f"Status code: {r.status_code}")

#Store API response in a variable
response_dict = r.json()

#Open a File for Writing
f = csv.writer(open(filename, "w", encoding='utf8'))

with open(filename, mode='w') as f:
    # Write CSV Header
    f.write("Computer_Name,"+"IP_Addresses"+"\n")
    for computer in response_dict["advanced_computer_search"]["computers"]:
        # filter blank line
        if computer["Computer_Name"] or computer["IP_Addresses"]:
            f.write("\""+computer["Computer_Name"]+"\","+"\""+computer["IP_Addresses"]+"\"\n")
```

Note that " around  value was build by appending `\"`. `\n` to change new line after each loop.

Comment: I ran that code without any errors but the file is not getting created. Also Pandas wasn't installed initially. It was easy to install on my personal laptop but when i move this to a corp environment even simple installations like this become difficult.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I found the file. So this works well but how do I add " " around the values in the CSV file output (or another delimiter if necessary)?

Comment: @JetRocket11 I have update my answer, hope that would help.

Comment: Excellent. Both options work and will test further.